# using purrr::map with action within function (not assigning the output to an object)

Tags: r, purrr

I'm trying to convert from loops to purrr for clarity and (often) better processing speeds

I have a variable number of Rdata files, say "AB.Rdata", "CD.Rdata", and "YZ.Rdata"
I've created a vector of Rdata names, `x.rdata`
I'd like to use `purrr::map` to load each element of the vector
the following does what I intend, but I suspect is not good practice

```
invisible(purrr::map(x.rdata, load, envir = .GlobalEnv))
```

I run into the same problem using `assign()` within `map()`
should I restrict using `map()` for when I only want to capture the final object?
Thanks

Comment: Seems like you might want `walk()` rather than `map()`.

Comment: maybe `walk()` is what you need - similar to `map()` but for cases where you are calling the function for its side effects.

Comment: thank you both `purrr::walk(x.rdata, load, envir = .GlobalEnv)` is already an improvement

Answer (score 2):

You can use walk as other said but for this I would just use base function `Vectorize` :

```
### build data, save it
dir.create("temp")
AB <- 1
CD <- 2
XY <- 3
x.rdata <- c("temp/AB.RData","temp/CD.RData","temp/XY.RData")
save(AB,file=x.rdata[1])
save(CD,file=x.rdata[2])
save(XY,file=x.rdata[3])

### remove, reload

rm(AB,CD,XY)
Vectorize(load,"file")(x.rdata,envir = .GlobalEnv)
c(AB,CD,XY) # [1] 1 2 3

rm(AB,CD,XY)
purrr::walk(x.rdata, load, envir = .GlobalEnv)
c(AB,CD,XY) # [1] 1 2 3

### clean up the mess
unlink("temp",T)
file.exists("temp") # FALSE
```